# My orientdb SQL query script execute too slow

Tags: java, database, orientdb

I have 5000 Events and 38 Dnodes, Relate is light, and my SQL script like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(tnode.aaa)) as abc from (MATCH {class: Dnode, as: snode, where:(name = 'uuid' and value='d8a30901a12d42a17e9050279aebccd2')}.in('Relate'){as: event, where:(ts >= 1509270057 and ts <= 1524822057)}.out('Relate'){ as: tnode, where:(name = 'haddr')} RETURN tnode )
```

Executed in 1.308 sec, how I optimize my query

Comment: You probably want to use `EXPLAIN` to figure out what is wrong with you query. https://orientdb.com/docs/2.0/orientdb.wiki/SQL-Explain.html

Comment: Hi, could you post an example of your structure? What version are you using?

Comment: orient version:orientdb-community-importers-2.2.33.tar.gz
 event:{
   "ei":"",
    "idCooper":"",
    "ts":""
}
CREATE INDEX event_ukey ON Event (ei,idCooper) UNIQUE_HASH_INDEX
CREATE INDEX event_ts_idcooper ON Event (ts,idCooper) NOTUNIQUE

Dnode:{
   "name":"",
   "value":"",
    "aaa":""
}
CREATE INDEX gnode_ukey ON Gnode (name,value) UNIQUE